# Car park cost calculator python 2.7 Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

Im very new to python and im currently trying to create gui for a program that calculates the cost of parking. When running the code there are no errors but the program doesn't produce a label with the calculated cost. I also want it to produce a message asking for a valid input code if the letters C,D or V are not entered into the entry boxes. Any help in where im going wrong would be appreciated! I know the layout doesn't look good at the moment i'm going to go back and fix the placement of labels afterwards its more getting core basics of the code working that i'm struggling with.

```
-- coding: cp1252 --
import Tkinter as tk 
import re 
from functools import partial

def Vehicle(label_result, n1, n2):
Vehicle = Vehicletypeentrytext.get()
Vehicle_upper = Vehicle.upper()
if not re.match("^[C,V,D]*$", Vehicle_upper):
    label_result.config(text="Please input valid vehicle code")
    return

elif Vehicle_upper=='C':
    def carcost(label_result, n1, n2):
        num1 = (n1.get())
        num2 = (n2.get())
        result = (int(num2)-int(num1))+1
        label_result.config(text="Cost for Parking is %d" % result)
        return

elif Vehicle_upper=='V':
    def vancost(label_result, n1, n2):
        num1 = (n1.get())
        num2 = (n2.get())
        result = (int(num1)-int(num2))+2
        label_result.config(text="Cost for Parking is%d" % result)
        return

elif Vehicle_upper=='D':
    def disabledcost(label_result, n1, n2):
        num1 = (n1.get())
        num2 = (n2.get())
        result = (int(num1)-int(num2))
        label_result.config(text="Cost for Parking is%d" % result)
        return


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')
root.title('Simple Calculator')

number1 = tk.StringVar()
number2 = tk.StringVar()

Title = tk.Label(root, text="SHORTSTAY CARPARK PAYMENT").grid(row=0, column=2)

Price = tk.Label(root, text = "1 hour = $2.00 / $3.00 / $1.00\n2 hour = $3.00 / $4.00 / $2.00\n3 hour = $4.00 / $5.00 / $3.00\n4 hour = $5.00 / $6.00 / $4.00\n").grid(row=1, column=0)

Vehicletypeentrytext = tk.StringVar()

Vehicletypelabel = tk.Label(root, text = 'Enter your Vehicle type:\nC for Car\tV for Van\tD for Disabled driver').grid(row=2, column=3)
Vehicletypeentry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=Vehicletypeentrytext).grid(row=4, column=3)

labelNum1 = tk.Label(root, text="Enter Time in:").grid(row=5, column=0)
labelNum2 = tk.Label(root, text="Enter Time Out:").grid(row=6, column=0)

entryNum1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=number1).grid(row=5, column=2)
entryNum2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=number2).grid(row=6, column=2)

labelResult = tk.Label(root)
labelResult.grid(row=7, column=2)

Vehicle = partial(Vehicle, labelResult, number1, number2)

buttonCal = tk.Button(root, text="Calculate", command=Vehicle).grid(row=7, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You were calling functions inside `def Vehicle(label_result, n1, n2)` which isn't adding anything to your script so it preventing the result to display as a `Label`.No need to create function inside your `if elif` statement.check my edit on your function `def Vehicle(label_result, n1, n2)`

```
import Tkinter as tk 
import re 
from functools import partial



def Vehicle(label_result, n1, n2):
    Vehicle = Vehicletypeentrytext.get()
    Vehicle_upper = Vehicle.upper()
    if not re.match("^[C,V,D]*$", Vehicle_upper):
        label_result.config(text="Please input valid vehicle code")
        return

    elif Vehicle_upper == 'C':
        num1 = (n1.get())
        num2 = (n2.get())
        result = (int(num2) - int(num1)) + 1
        label_result.config(text="Cost for Parking is %d" %  result)

        return

    elif Vehicle_upper == 'V':
        num1 = (n1.get())
        num2 = (n2.get())
        result = (int(num1) - int(num2)) + 2
        label_result.config(text="Cost for Parking is%d" %  result)
        return


    elif Vehicle_upper == 'D':
        num1 = (n1.get())
        num2 = (n2.get())
        result = (int(num1) - int(num2))
        label_result.config(text="Cost for Parking is%d" %  result)
        return



root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')
root.title('Simple Calculator')

number1 = tk.StringVar()
number2 = tk.StringVar()

Title = tk.Label(root, text="SHORTSTAY CARPARK PAYMENT").grid(row=0, column=2)

Price = tk.Label(root, text = "1 hour = $2.00 / $3.00 / $1.00\n2 hour = $3.00 / $4.00 / $2.00\n3 hour = $4.00 / $5.00 / $3.00\n4 hour = $5.00 / $6.00 / $4.00\n").grid(row=1, column=0)

Vehicletypeentrytext = tk.StringVar()

Vehicletypelabel = tk.Label(root, text = 'Enter your Vehicle type:\nC for Car\tV for Van\tD for Disabled driver').grid(row=2, column=3)
Vehicletypeentry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=Vehicletypeentrytext).grid(row=4, column=3)

labelNum1 = tk.Label(root, text="Enter Time in:").grid(row=5, column=0)
labelNum2 = tk.Label(root, text="Enter Time Out:").grid(row=6, column=0)

entryNum1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=number1).grid(row=5, column=2)
entryNum2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=number2).grid(row=6, column=2)

labelResult = tk.Label(root)
labelResult.grid(row=7, column=2)

Vehicle = partial(Vehicle, labelResult, number1, number2)

buttonCal = tk.Button(root, text="Calculate", command=Vehicle).grid(row=7, 
column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @samuel west if this solve your problem kindly select it as an answer